# Contract period: Automatically extended for three year periods

Tags: meaning

I confused this sentence so much.

This general agreement shall remain in effect for three years. It will be automatically extended for three year periods.

Is it mean that the agreement will be renewed every three year period? or valid only 6 years?

Comment: The words *automatically* and *periods* tell you 3 + 3 + 3 + ...

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552551/contract-period-automatically-renewed-for-another-five-year-periods-at-the-expi), Anna? I see that the length of the agreement is different. If it is related take note of jsw's comment on my answer to your other question, you might need to ask a lawyer.

Comment: Thank BoldBen, I have many cases of duration of contract and it makes me crazy! Some is another 5 year periods, other is further five years, another is subsequent 5 year periods. :(

Answer (score 0):

The plural “periods” tells you that at the end of each period, it will be extended for another period, and so on indefinitely.

If they meant only one additional period, they would have used the singular “period”.

In both cases, you would expect to see some additional language about how one or both parties can prevent the automatic extension; usually in such contracts neither party can cancel a period that has already started—at least without cause—so this is the only way to keep it from becoming permanent.